# Highcharts categories with many curves is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I'm new using Highcharts. Using it in iOS (which is pretty much the same as JS) I have this piece of code for testing:

```
private func initChart(){
    let chart = HIChart()
    let chartOptions = HIOptions()
    chartOptions.chart = chart

    chart.type = "line"

    chartOptions.title = HITitle()
    chartOptions.title.text = "Auction Details"

    chartOptions.subtitle = HISubtitle()
    chartOptions.subtitle.text = "P&L Curves"

    let xAxis = HIXAxis()
    xAxis.title = HITitle()
    xAxis.title.text = "Time"
    xAxis.categories = ["10-01-2018", "23-03-2018", "10-04-2018", "30-04-2018", "01-05-2018", "14-09-2018", "10-011-2018", "22-11-2018"]
    chartOptions.xAxis = [xAxis]

    let yAxis = HIYAxis()
    yAxis.title = HITitle()
    yAxis.title.text = "Money"
    yAxis.min = 0.0
    chartOptions.yAxis = [yAxis]

    let seriesRewards = HISeries()
    seriesRewards.name = "Rewards"
    seriesRewards.data = [["10-01-2018", 23.4], ["23-03-2018", 34.2], ["22-11-2018",7.9]]

    let seriesPrice = HISeries()
    seriesPrice.name = "Price"
    seriesPrice.data = [["23-03-2018",42.4], ["23-03-2018",34.2], ["10-04-2018",61.1], ["01-05-2018",87.0], ["14-09-2018",25.9], ["22-11-2018",100.1], ["01-12-2018",95.9], ["22-12-2018",81.9]]

    chartOptions.series = [seriesRewards, seriesPrice]

    chartView.options = chartOptions
}
```

This runs perfectly but it I the points for the 1st series do not match with what I said... pls take a look to the following image:

[image: The last point for the 1st series is not correct]

My question is, seriesRewards is defined like this:

> seriesRewards.data = [["10-01-2018", 23.4], ["23-03-2018", 34.2],
>   ["22-11-2018",7.9]]

Why the last point is not shown in the correct position in the chart?

Regards

Comment: You're using `xAxis.categories`, so each point belongs to the particular category. What you need is xAxis type `datetime` and data passed as `[[1542014107109, 23.4], ....... ]` -> `[timestamp, y-value]`. Check docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: Thanks a lot @WojciechChmiel, but now I have another issue. Pints don't appear in the curve if I remove xAxis.categories... because if you see the image above, each point has a circle or a diamond as icon or something like that to represent the point... using your approach the curve is ok, but I'm missing this.  Any idea how to enable them in iOS?

Comment: Have you tried just enable the markers? Api: https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/.